# Content Rights when submitting app to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

When submitting an app to the app store I've been asked this question:

```
"Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?".
```

I wanted to know if my app is for image sharing and have access to the user image gallery and camera, should I answer Yes or No to that question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I read this you are the first party, and your user is the second party. If you get photos from somewhere else and show them to your user, that's third-party. So, NO.

Answer (score 3):

I would answer "No" as you aren't pulling in content from third parties, only the user of your app.